# Generating random password with requirements

Tags: php

I am using the code below to generate a password, but I need it to meet the requirement of always having at least 1 special character and 1 number. How can I do this?

```
function generatePassword($_len) {

  $_alphaSmall = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';            // small letters
  $_alphaCaps  = strtoupper($_alphaSmall);                // CAPITAL LETTERS
  $_numerics   = '1234567890';                            // numerics
  $_specialChars = '%-#_*@';                              // Special Characters

  $_container = $_alphaSmall.$_alphaCaps.$_numerics.$_specialChars;   // Contains all characters
  $password = '';         // will contain the desired pass - will use later

  for($i = 0; $i < $_len; $i++) {                                 // Loop till the length mentioned
      $_rand = rand(0, strlen($_container) - 1);                  // Get Randomized Length
      $password .= substr($_container, $_rand, 1);                // returns part of the string 
  }

  return $password;       // Test Returns the generated Pass
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: You're putting all the available classes together and then picking across the whole superset, which obviously doesn't guarantee you'll get one from each class. You could instead start by explicitly picking a few from `$_numerics`, then pick a few from `$_specialChars`, then pick the rest from `$_alphaSmall` and `$_alphaCaps`. Then put them all together and shuffle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important question here is whether you want your string to contain a number and special character for actual security reasons (which doesn't make sense with this algorithm, as it would increase, not decrease, the guess-ability of the password), or to satisfy the requirements of specific websites or other services.

In the latter case, the simplest method is probably to add a number and special character to the end of the string. In the former, you can add them to the end and then shuffle the string, to keep their position from being predictable.

```
 function generatePassword($_len) {

  $_alphaSmall = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';            // small letters
  $_alphaCaps  = strtoupper($_alphaSmall);                // CAPITAL LETTERS
  $_numerics   = '1234567890';                            // numerics
  $_specialChars = '%-#_*@';                              // Special Characters

  $_container = $_alphaSmall.$_alphaCaps.$_numerics.$_specialChars;   // Contains all characters
  $password = '';         // will contain the desired pass - will use later

  for($i = 2; $i < $_len; $i++) {                                 // Loop till two characters less than the desired length
      $_rand = rand(0, strlen($_container) - 1);                  // Get Randomized Length
      $password .= substr($_container, $_rand, 1);                // returns part of the string 
  }
  $password .= substr($_numerics, rand(0, strlen($_numerics) - 1), 1);    // Add a number
  $password .= substr($_specialChars, rand(0, strlen($_specialChars) - 1), 1);    // Add a special character

    // Shuffle the password characters because the number and the special characters comes at fixed position
    $passwordArray = str_split($password);
    shuffle($passwordArray);
    $password = implode('', $passwordArray);

  return $password;       // Test Returns the generated Pass
}
```

Comment: The one issue with this code is that the returned password is 2 characters longer than what was requested of it. Simple fix: set `$i=2` in the for loop condition.

Comment: That's true, I'll make that change.